# Gedit stating that its unable to retrieve file info even though it works

Tags: 11.10, gtk, gedit

While this isn't causing any serious issues (that I've seen so far), it is  aggravating me because its taking over the terminal window that I was working on with the warning:

```
(gedit:3288): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to retrieve the file info for `file:///home/amn/Programming/Java/MyLiero/Driver.java': Error stating file '/home/amn/Programming/Java/MyLiero/Driver.java': No such file or directory
```

However, the file opens up fine and is editable/savable and everything still exists after the program is closed.  When you start the program again, it still sees everything and no more errors come about.  This error only appears when you create directories - it doesn't matter if the saved item occurs within the directory or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you started `gedit` from terminal using

```
gedit myfilename.blah
```

in this case `gedit`'s standard output and standard error streams are connected to the terminal so any debug info is getting printed to the terminal.

To get rid of the messages, you can redirect stdout and stderr to `/dev/null`:

```
gedit myfilename.blah > /dev/null 2>&1
```